# Pandas sum column with variable subarray length and add more columns to result

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to sum/arrange data in dataframe. I have following data

```
                                  time       t2m  ...        av      kont
latitude longitude                                ...                    
46.5     18.0      1998-01-12 07:00:00  0.284698  ...  0.001613          
         18.0      1998-01-24 08:00:00 -1.304504  ...  0.001418  FROMHERE
         18.0      1998-01-24 09:00:00 -1.113770  ...  0.002679          
         18.0      1998-01-24 17:00:00  0.345001  ...  0.004633  FROMHERE
         18.0      1998-01-24 18:00:00 -0.122498  ...  0.004400          
         18.0      1998-01-24 19:00:00  0.041565  ...  0.002184          
         18.0      1998-01-24 20:00:00  0.100861  ...  0.002220          
         18.0      1998-01-24 21:00:00  0.120636  ...  0.003083          
         18.0      1998-01-24 22:00:00 -0.615662  ...  0.004330          
         18.0      1998-01-24 23:00:00 -0.686798  ...  0.002404          
         18.0      1998-01-25 00:00:00 -0.743134  ...  0.000953          
         18.0      1998-01-29 02:00:00 -4.786346  ...  0.002984  FROMHERE
```

My goal is to sum data in `av` column between `FROMWHERE` cells and add starting and ending dates in `time` column. My output should look like this:

```
                         t2m  ...       kont    sum             d1                  d2
latitude longitude            ...           
46.5     18.0       0.284698  ...               0.001613        1998-01-12 07:00:00 1998-01-24 08:00:00
         18.0      -1.304504  ...   FROMHERE    0.004097        1998-01-24 08:00:00 1998-01-24 09:00:00
         18.0       0.345001  ...   FROMHERE    0.024207        1998-01-24 17:00:00 1998-01-25 00:00:00         
         18.0      -4.786346  ...   FROMHERE    xxxxxx
```

Column `kont` is created from df.loc from another columns in attempt to sum these sub-arrays, but I am pretty much stuck here.

Since amount of data is huge, Im looking for solution based on native Pandas  functionalities(vectored calculations).

Any help/idea is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically an island-and-gap problem. Every line contains `FROMHERE` forms a new island. You can approach that using `cumsum`:

```
    kont  cumsum
    None       0
FROMHERE       1
    None       1
FROMHERE       2
    None       2
    None       2
    None       2
    None       2
    None       2
    None       2
    None       2
FROMHERE       3
```

The code:

```
def summarize(group):
    s = group['kont'].eq('FROMHERE').cumsum()
    return group.groupby(s).agg(
        t2m=('t2m', 'first'),
        sum=('av', 'sum'),
        d1=('time', 'min'),
        d2=('time', 'max')
    )

df.groupby(['latitude', 'longitude']).apply(summarize).reset_index(level=-1, drop=True)
```