# Custom function in Pandas aggregation

Tags: python, pandas

I have a following dataframe - [result from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58775168/pandas-sum-column-with-variable-subarray-length-and-add-more-columns-to-result):

```
                         t2m  ...       kont    sum             d1                  d2
latitude longitude            ...           
46.5     18.0       0.284698  ...               0.001613        1998-01-12 07:00:00 1998-01-24 08:00:00
         18.0      -1.304504  ...   FROMHERE    0.004097        1998-01-24 08:00:00 1998-01-24 09:00:00
         18.0       0.345001  ...   FROMHERE    0.024207        1998-01-24 17:00:00 1998-01-25 00:00:00         
         18.0      -4.786346  ...   FROMHERE    xxxxxx
```

I want to implement combination of custom and build in functions to `.agg` of this dataframe.
Here is the code:

```
dfgeo=df.groupby(['latitude', 'longitude']).agg(
                 std=('sum',np.std),
                 maks=('sum','max'),
                 mean=('sum',(lambda x: mean(absolute(x - mean(x)))))
                 ).reset_index()
```

Code `mean=('sum',(lambda x: mean(absolute(x - mean(x)))))` mimics Mean Average Deviation since is not directly build in Numpy, or i cant find it.
I get following error:

```
KeyError: "[('ar', '<lambda>')] not in index"
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you try removing that brackets around lambda?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me working custom function:

```
def f(x):
    return np.mean(np.abs(x - np.mean(x)))

dfgeo=df.groupby(['latitude', 'longitude']).agg(
                 std=('sum',np.std),
                 maks=('sum','max'),
                 mean=('sum',f)
                 ).reset_index()
```